# How would I go about making mouseover items unique in my timeline?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am busy developing a small timeline using the hover function jquery and have run into a bit of wall. Currenly I have two classes one for the date at the top of the timeline and one for the date at the bottom of the timeline. Each work with a JQUERY hover function, so when you hover over the date on the top one some text comes up and the same for the bottom. The issue I having is that once you start duplicating the list items the hovers are no longer individual and are controlled by the duplicated classes, how would I go about creating some sort of differentiation so this does not occur.

I have included a JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/Jason1975/6nwkd2c8/10/ this show the issue exactly.

Some guidance would would be greatly appreciated.

HTML CODE

```
 <div id="container">
 <ul id="new">
 <!-- Block Up Date on top -->
 <li class="block-up">
    <p class="date-up"><a href="" id="1">24 January 2015</a></p>
    <p class="event-up">This event happend on this date</p>
 </li>
 <!-- Block Down Date at the bottom -->
 <li class="block-down">
    <p class="event-down">This event happend on this date</p>
    <p class="date-down"><a href="" >24 February 2015</a></p>
 </li>
 <!-- Block Up Date on top -->
 <li class="block-up">
    <p class="date-up"><a href="">24 January 2015</a></p>
    <p class="event-up">This event happend on this date</p>
 </li>
 <!-- Block Down Date at the bottom -->
 <li class="block-down">
    <p class="event-down">This event happend on this date</p>
    <p class="date-down"><a href="">24 February 2015</a></p>
 </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
 <script src="js/jquery_1-11.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--the toggle-->
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".block-up a").hover(function(){
 $(".event-up").css('visibility', 'visible');
 },
 function() {
 $(".event-up").css('visibility', 'hidden');
 });
 $(".block-down a").hover(function(){
 $(".event-down").css('visibility', 'visible');
 },
 function() {
 $(".event-down").css('visibility', 'hidden');
 });
 });
 </script>
```

CSS

```
 a  { font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none; color: #666666; }
 a:hover    { font-size: 14px; color: #F47C00;  }
 /* Timeline */
 #container {   width: 800px;
            height: 80px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space:nowrap;
            background:url(../images/line.png) center 50% repeat-x;
 }
 ul#new {  display: inline;  }
.block-up   {   position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            list-style:none;
            width: 200px;
            height: 80px;
            margin: 0!important;
            top: 0;
            background: url(../images/dot.png) center 50% no-repeat;
 }
 .block-down {  position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            list-style:none;
            width: 200px;
            height: 80px;
            margin: 0!important;
            top: 0;
            background: url(../images/dot.png) center 50% no-repeat;
 }
 .block-down a  { font-size: 14px; }
 .block-down a:hover    { font-size: 14px; }
 .date-up {         padding-bottom: 20px;
            text-align:center;
 }
 .event-up {    padding-top: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #F47C00;
            visibility: hidden;
  }
 .date-down {   padding-top: 20px;
            text-align:center;
 }
 .event-down {  padding-bottom: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #F47C00;
            visibility:hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you then see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/khanshaban/6nwkd2c8/12/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".block-up a").hover(function(){
$(this).parent().parent().find(".event-up").css('visibility', 'visible');
},
function() {
$(".event-up").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
$(".block-down a").hover(function(){
$(this).parent().parent().find(".event-down").css('visibility', 'visible');
},
function() {
$(".event-down").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
});
```

Comment: You should really improve your answer instead of just throwing in a JSFiddle. What have you added to the code? Why? Etc.

Comment: You got me, that fixes my exact problem. much appreciated.

Comment: I have only change jQuery code only . i have used $(this) , because where you pointed it finds the required div and show it. $(this) is your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/6nwkd2c8/17/).

```
$(function() {
    function findEvent(el) {
        return el.className.indexOf('up') >= 0 ? $(el).next() : $(el).prev();    
    }
    $('.date-down, .date-up').hover(function(){
        findEvent(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function(){
        findEvent(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    })    
});
```

Or better add common classes for up and down blocks: `block, event, date`. And use those classes to hook up behaivour.